# Bluetooth Broken

Tags: bluetooth, notification-area

Bluetooth Icon has disappeared from the notification area. From the Settings menu, both "On/Off" and "Visibility" are grayed out and cannot be changed. "Show Bluetooth status in the menu bar" is checked (box is checked and red.) Un-checking it and re-checking it didn't help. I have searched the blogs far and wide to no avail. Suggestions as to how to get Bluetooth working again?

Just noticed that I am running 16.04.4...don't know how that happened as I did not initiate the update from .3 nonetheless could this be a bug?